# How to handle missing values from VirtualKey enumeration in KeyRoutedEventArgs e

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, input

Using C#, I'm extending the Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBox class to handle custom formatting of input as the user types. My logic is called from two event handlers, one for the TextChanged event (for attempts to paste data) and another for the KeyDown event (for typed input).

My problem concerns the KeyDown event and its arguments, which are contained in a [KeyRoutedEventArgs class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.input.keyroutedeventargs.aspx). The key press itself is described by the [VirtualKey enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.virtualkey.aspx).

Unfortunately that enumeration is missing many keys, such as a comma, tilde, or even backspace.

Additionally, Delete is present, but when you press it the TextChanged event gets handled before the KeyDown event. This can mess with the behavior of my control.

Is there another way of handling typed data that would give me the control I need in my custom control?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Backspace is available, it is VirtualKey.Back.

The comma key is normally Oemcomma, it is (VirtualKey)188.  The tilde character normally requires holding down the Shift key and pressing the Oem8 key, it is (VirtualKey)223.  In my neck of the woods but not on a Spanish keyboard, they use it a lot so have a dedicated ñ key and they have to press AltGr + D4 to get a plain tilde.  You can usually reverse-engineer other missing ones by having a look at the [System.Windows.Forms.Keys](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Keys.cs,c9ea55b52b93f5c4) enumeration and/or using the debugger.

The acronym OEM provides a hint why these virtual key codes are missing.  OEM means Original Equipment Manufacturer.  The people that actually design and manufacture keyboards.  It is at their discretion to do whatever they want with the oem keys.  Like completely omit them or give them an entirely different function or moving them into an unusual location.  The kind of thing that can happen with keyboards used by people in far-flung places on planet Earth.  Some keyboard layouts are stunningly difficult to use to a Western user.  Not by the locals of course.

In other words, these virtual key codes were intentionally omitted because you can't depend on those keys actually being useful or present on the user's device.  So you should not use them.  Microsoft aggressively removed features from WinRT that caused chronic localization problems.

Comment: Thanks, the description of Back as "The virtual back key or button" had me thinking it wasn't backspace, but the back button. I see now that the back button is actually enumerated as GoBack.